# Active Slide in Swiper.js - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am trying to get a piece of text to appear when the Swiper Slide is active (centered) and then disappear when it is not the center/active slide. I have tried two options, one using the `isActive` parameter from Swiper and another trying to create my own function using `class.contains("class")`.

From looking at the classes, the centered slide doesn't actually look like the "Active" slide. This is why I have used `swiper-slide-next` as the class name in my function as it is the centered slide.

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Carousel.module.scss";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/swiper.scss";
import SwiperCore, { Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation } from "swiper";

const Carousel = () => {
  SwiperCore.use([Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation]);

  const textJsx = () => {
    const card = document.querySelector(".productCard");
    if (card.classList.contains("swiper-slide-next")) {
      return <p>i'm center/next</p>;
    }
    {
      return <p>Shouldnt be here s</p>;
    }
  };

  let cardData = [
    {
      img: "email.svg",
      title: "email",
      para: "variable text ",
    },
    {
      img: "facebook.svg",
      title: "facebook",
      para: "variable text ",
    },
    {
      img: "instagram.svg",
      title: "insta",
      para: "variable text ",
    },
    {
      img: "linkedin.svg",
      title: "linked",
      para: "variable text ",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        autoplay={{
          delay: 3000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        }}
        navigation={{
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        }}
        spaceBetween={30}
        autoHeight={true}
        loop={true}
        slidesPerView={1}
        // onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
        // onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
        breakpoints={{
          768: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 40,
          },
          902: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 50,
          },
        }}
      >
        {cardData.map((card) => {
          return (
            <SwiperSlide key={card.title}>
              <div className={styles.productCard}>
                <img src={card.img} alt={card.title} />
                <h2>{card.title}</h2>
                {({ isActive }) => (
                  <div>
                    Current slide is{" "}
                    {isActive ? <p>{card.para}</p> : <p>not active</p>}
                    {textJsx()}
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
          );
        })}
      </Swiper>
      <div class="swiper-button-next">next arrow</div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev">prev arrow</div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Carousel;
```